# Invalid Column Name in VB.Net code behind

Tags: vb.net

I am getting an error in VB.Net code behind like this: `Invalid column name`

the SQL select statement I am using is:

```
Dim Concstr As String = "Tit_one"
Dim strquery As String
strquery = "SELECT  Title from " & TitleTableName & " WHERE TitleCode = " & Concstr & "
```

Comment: So doe the columns `Title` and `TitleCode` exist in table `TitleTableName`(whatever that is)? Also, use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation to prevent sql-injection.

Comment: It seems like the table "TitleTableName" has no column "Title"...

Comment: The immediate error is that you have not put single-quotes around the parameter string. The overall error is that you have not used SQL parameters for the query.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know what your table is called, so we'll use "Titles" for now.)

If you do the concatenation by hand that you wrote code for, your SQL query comes out like this:

```
SELECT  Title from Titles WHERE TitleCode = Tit_one
```

When you want to search a column for a value that is a string, the value has to be in single quotes, or the database will think you are comparing the values in two columns, i.e., `TitleCode` and `Tit_one`. There probably isn't a column called `Tit_one`, and this is why you see the error message.

So the right format is

```
SELECT  Title from Titles WHERE TitleCode = 'Tit_one'
```

and your code should look like

```vb
strquery = "SELECT  Title from " & TitleTableName & " WHERE TitleCode = '" & Concstr & "'"
```

Note that this is fine for learning how to use a database in VB, but in the long term, you should find out how to use [SQL query parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms254953.aspx) to avoid security problems in your code.